# Intento modificar un dato en SQLite desde un item de ListView personalizado pero se cambian todos al itentar modificar uno

Tags: java, android, listview, onclick

Primera pregunta que hago en stackoverflow por que estoy confuso, intento cambiar un dato en SQLite desde un ListView personalizado y resulta que se cambian todos los datos y solo quiero cambiar el del ítem seleccionado.
Intento cambiar aolo un dato en SQLite pero por alguna razón se cambian todos.

**Codigo del getView**   en el getView del adaptador tengo dos botones y uno de esos quiero que modifique un dato en SQLite que cambie el saldo`

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View vista = view;


        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        vista=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_cliente,null);

        TextView lblnombre = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.lblnombre);
        final EditText lblabono = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtabonoitem);
        TextView lblletrasatraso = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.lblletrasatrasoitem);
        TextView lblcotasdeatraso = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.lblcotasdeatrasoitem);
        TextView lblcotaspendientes = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.lblcotaspendientesitem);
        lblsaldo = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.lblsaldoitem);
        TextView lblcota = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.lblcotadiriaitem);
        TextView lblplazo = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.lblplazoitem);
        final ProgressBar progresoplata = (ProgressBar) vista.findViewById(R.id.progresobar);
        final ProgressBar progresodia = (ProgressBar) vista.findViewById(R.id.progresobardia);
        final ProgressBar progreoscargando = (ProgressBar) vista.findViewById(R.id.progresocargando);
        TextView lbldiaprestado = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.lbldiaprestadoitem);
        TextView lblmodalidad = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.lblmodalidaditem);
        TextView lblcedula = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.lblcedulaitem);
        TextView lblcobrador = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.lblcobradoritem);
        final TextView lblcodigo = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.lblcodigoitem);
        final TextView lbltelefono = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.lbltelefonoitem);
        TextView lbldireccion = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.lblobservacionitem);
        final TextView lblobservacion = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.lblobservacionitem);

        Button pagar = (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.btnpagaritem);
        Button llamar = (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.btnllamaritem);

        lblnombre.setText(ListaObejtos.get(position).getNombre().toString());
        lblabono.setText(ListaObejtos.get(position).getAbono().toString());
        lblletrasatraso.setText(ListaObejtos.get(position).getLetrasatraso().toString());
        lblcotasdeatraso.setText(ListaObejtos.get(position).getAtraso().toString());
        lblcotaspendientes.setText(ListaObejtos.get(position).getAtraso().toString());
        lblsaldo.setText(ListaObejtos.get(position).getSaldo().toString());
        lblcota.setText(ListaObejtos.get(position).getCota().toString());
        lblplazo.setText(ListaObejtos.get(position).getPlazo().toString());
        progresoplata.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(ListaObejtos.get(position).getProgreosdinero().toString()));
        progresodia.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(ListaObejtos.get(position).getProgresodia().toString()));
        lbldiaprestado.setText(ListaObejtos.get(position).getDiaPrestado().toString());
        lblmodalidad.setText(ListaObejtos.get(position).getModalidad().toString());
        lblcedula.setText(ListaObejtos.get(position).getCedula().toString());
        lblcobrador.setText(ListaObejtos.get(position).getCobrador().toString());
        lblcodigo.setText(ListaObejtos.get(position).getCodigo().toString());
        lbltelefono.setText(ListaObejtos.get(position).getTelefono().toString());
        lbldireccion.setText(ListaObejtos.get(position).getDireccion().toString());
        lblobservacion.setText(ListaObejtos.get(position).getObservacion().toString());



        progreoscargando.setIndeterminate(false);

        pagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int abn = Integer.parseInt(ListaObejtos.get(position).getAbono().toString());
                int sal = Integer.parseInt(ListaObejtos.get(position).getSaldo().toString());
                int abono = Integer.parseInt(lblabono.getText().toString());
                int saldo = Integer.parseInt(lblsaldo.getText().toString());
                String codigo = ListaObejtos.get(position).getCodigo().toString();
                String observacion = lblobservacion.getText().toString();

                final int resultado = saldo-abono;

                mensajeToast("Abono "+abono);
                lblsaldo.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));
                progresodia.setProgress(abono);
                progresoplata.setProgress(resultado);
                progreoscargando.setIndeterminate(true);

                pagarSQL(resultado,codigo,observacion);
                update();
            }
        });

        llamar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String telefono = lbltelefono.getText().toString();
                mensajeToast("Llamando..."+telefono);
                progreoscargando.setIndeterminate(false);
            }
        });

        return vista;
    }
```

El código del **botón en el getView** es este

```
pagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int abn = Integer.parseInt(ListaObejtos.get(position).getAbono().toString());
                int sal = Integer.parseInt(ListaObejtos.get(position).getSaldo().toString());
                int abono = Integer.parseInt(lblabono.getText().toString());
                int saldo = Integer.parseInt(lblsaldo.getText().toString());
                String codigo = ListaObejtos.get(position).getCodigo().toString();
                String observacion = lblobservacion.getText().toString();

                final int resultado = saldo-abono;

                mensajeToast("Abono "+abono);
                lblsaldo.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));
                progresodia.setProgress(abono);
                progresoplata.setProgress(resultado);
                progreoscargando.setIndeterminate(true);

                pagarSQL(resultado,codigo,observacion);
                update();
            }
        });
```

El **evento pagarSQL** que es el que se encarga de modificar el saldo en la base de datos SQLite

```
  private void pagarSQL(int saldo,String codigo,String observacion){

        BaseDatos admin = new BaseDatos(context,
                "admin", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();
        registro.put("saldo", saldo);
        registro.put("observacion", observacion);
        registro.put("diapago",fechaActual());

        int cant = bd.update("clientes", registro, "codigo=" + codigo, null);
        bd.close();

        if (cant == 1) {
            lblsaldo.setText(saldo);
            HacerPagos2 i = new HacerPagos2();
            i.notificacion("Pago realizado localmente ", Color.GREEN);
        }
    }
```

Cuando presiono el botón se me actualiza todos los saldos de todos los datos registrados con el mismo saldo del ítem, es como si recorriera un blucle registro por registro cambiando todos los saldos por el saldo del ítem cambiado

Comment: Hola Andres agrega que realiza el método update() , me parece que ese puede ser el problema. Te refieres a que te actualiza todos los datos de la tabla?

Comment: @Jorgesys tienes razón, ese uptade borraba toda la lista y la creaba  ahí estaba el error, lo había creado para actualizar la lista. pero ahora la actualizo cambiando solo el item con el método set(position,valor)